# How to create PagingQueryProvider with multiple sortKeys?

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-batch

I want to create a `distinct on` query with `PagingQueryProvider`:

```
    PostgresPagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new PostgresPagingQueryProvider();
    queryProvider.setSelectClause("DISTINCT ON (first, second) *");
    queryProvider.setFromClause("mytable");
    Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>();
    sortKeys.put("first", Order.ASCENDING);
    sortKeys.put("second", Order.ASCENDING);
    sortKeys.put("third", Order.ASCENDING);
    queryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
```

Resulting sql generated from the provider:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(first, second) * FROM mytable ORDER BY first ASC, second ASC, third ASC;
```

Error:

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified
```

This query would be ok if it would be generated as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(first, second) * FROM mytable ORDER BY first, second, third ASC;
```

But as its not: how can I achieve a correct distinct here?
What is strange: when running the last query in pgAdmin against the DB, everything works correctly. BUt the query created by the `PagingQueryProvider` fails.

Comment: I'm not a Postgres guru, but are you saying that both order by columns have to be the same direction with a distinct?  For example, this wouldn't work?  `SELECT DISTINCT ON(first, second) * FROM mytable ORDER BY first DESC, second ASC;`

Comment: `ORDER BY first DESC, second ASC` does not work either as the syntax expected for the distinct is `first, second <order>`.